Connection between Noether's theorem for gauge theories and 1-form symmetries?
Applying Noether's theorem to a gauge theory, one can show that the conserved current is generically of the form
$$J^\mu=\partial_\nu k^{[\mu\nu]},$$
such that the conserved charge is really determined by the integral of $k$ on a codimension-2 surface $\Sigma$,
$$Q=\int_\Sigma d\Sigma_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu\nu}.$$
For example, for pure Maxwell theory, the Noether current is (up to equations of motion) $J^\mu=\partial_\nu(F^{\mu\nu}\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the gauge transformation parameter. In particular, this leads to the usual notion of electric charge:
$$Q=\int_\Sigma d\Sigma_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}.$$
It feels like I should be able to identify $k$ with a global one-form symmetry. In particular, a conserved two-form current $\partial_\mu J^{\mu\nu}=0$ can be integrated over a codimension-two submanifold to give a one-form charge
$$Q=\int_\Sigma d\Sigma_{\mu\nu}J^{\mu\nu}.$$
For example, $J^{\mu\nu}=F^{\mu\nu}$ in Maxwell theory generates the electric one-form symmetry that acts on Wilson lines. At least for Maxwell theory, it is clear that the charge associated to the gauge symmetry is also a global charge of a one-form symmetry. So is there a precise sense in which I can always identify these two pictures? That is, is it always true that a gauge symmetry has an associated one-form symmetry with the same charges?

Are you following a reference? Which page?

I wasn't specifically following any reference. However, a review of the generalized Noether theorem can be found in Section 1.2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07064, and a review of one-form symmetries in Maxwell theory can be found in Chapter V of https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.01817.
